# Bad character sequence handling

Tags: c++, c++11, buffer-overflow

I'm testing some newbie things, so I made this quick code to test if when I type an input larger than 1 byte, the code will crash. I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char ch1[1];
    std::cout << "Type a char:\n" ;
    std::cin >> ch1 ;
    std::cout << "\nHere is your char:" << ch1 << "\n" ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

1.-I tried to type an "A" and it's okay, all worked, and then the program outputted ("A").
2.-I tried to type an input of a special character like "", so the code crashed and printed the last lines of the code on the screen and exited.
3.-Then I tried to type a "€", so the program printed "?" as output (seems like it can't save all data).
4.-Finally, I tried to type a lot of characters, something like "l"laqiuldldlsjcbj", and the program printed it correctly.
So, in the second step, I thought I understood how it worked, but in 4th I see that I didn't.

I understand that when entering "€" in the output, it shows a "?" since it will only save part of the character information because it is too long. However, I don't understand why, when entering "lsaldjlafdhsal" as a string, the program does not crash, but when entering "", it crashes. The logical thing would be that it would crash in both cases, right?

Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Use `std::string`

Comment: "Yes, of course, but why can a lot of characters be well outputted and not '€'? Are many characters <1 byte and '€' and '' > 1 byte? And why doesn't '' behave the same way as '€' in this case?"

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Any assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Long time ago, people got together and came up with a standard enumerating system for characters and control code.  The term was **A**merican **S**tandard **C**ode for **I**nformation **I**nterchange, or ASCII.  The official ASCII code has 127 slots, so it would easily fit into 8-bits.  At the time of the standard, the 8th bit was often used as a Parity check so it was unavailable for encoding; thus the 127 quantity instead of 256.  Modern computer now may require more bytes to represent all the different symbols.  It is now called UNICODE.

Comment: On most platforms, the type `char` is to represent ASCII encodings.  You can have an extra bit if the `char` type is defined as unsigned.  The characters you are inputting do not fit into an 8-bit encoding.  You'll need to have more bits; multi-byte.  There are different standards for multi-byte encodings, any thing from `wchar` to `utf8`, `utf16` or `utf32`.  If you write a program to enter a `char`, you need to enter something in the range of type `char`.  Anything else is *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews , Thank you very much. It has helped me understand it a little better.